# mysql 5.6: group_concat help sought

Tags: mysql

I have the tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buildingAccess` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `building` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
      `person` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
      `enteryDate` datetime NOT NULL,
      `exitDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `buildingAccess` (`id`, `building`, `person`, `enteryDate`, `exitDate`) VALUES
    (1, 'Lot B-3', 'Alice Jones', '2015-11-10 05:29:14', '2015-11-10 15:18:42'),
    (3, 'Lot B-3', 'Alice Jones', '2015-11-11 07:11:27', '2015-11-11 12:43:34'),
    (7, 'Lot B-3', 'Alice Jones', '2015-12-10 07:11:27', '2015-12-11 12:43:34'),
    (2, 'Lot B-3', 'Bill Mayhew', '2015-11-10 10:29:14', '2015-11-10 12:18:42'),
    (4, 'Lot B-3', 'Bill Mayhew', '2015-11-12 09:10:27', '2015-11-13 02:43:34'),
    (8, 'Lot B-3', 'Bill Mayhew', '2015-11-12 09:10:27', '2015-11-13 02:43:34'),
    (5, 'Lot B-3', 'Charlotte Ahn', '2015-12-01 05:29:14', NULL),
    (6, 'Lot B-3', 'Dennis Lowe', '2015-12-10 10:29:14', '2015-12-10 12:18:42');

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buildingNotes` (
      `building` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
      `observer` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
      `observationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
      `note` varchar(64) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `buildingNotes` (`building`, `observer`, `observationDate`, `note`) VALUES
    ('Lot B-3', 'Alice Jones', '2015-11-10 05:32:12', 'burned out light on pole South-22'),
    ('Lot B-3', 'Alice Jones', '2015-11-10 05:39:12', 'burned out light on pole West-7'),
    ('Lot B-3', 'Alice Jones', '2015-11-10 05:42:12', 'overfull trash can near pole North-11'),
    ('Lot B-3', 'Charlotte Ahn', '2015-12-01 06:09:14', 'change drawr running low at gate 3');

    ALTER TABLE `buildingAccess`
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `building` (`building`,`person`,`enteryDate`,`exitDate`);

    ALTER TABLE `buildingNotes`
     ADD KEY `building` (`building`,`observer`,`observationDate`,`note`);

    ALTER TABLE `buildingAccess`
    MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=9;
```

My goal is a query that returns a list of all records in the `buildingAccess` table.  Each should have a `notes` field that is the `GROUP_CONCAT` of all of the `buildingNotes.note` entries made during that record's dates/times bracketed by `buildingAccess.enteryDate` and `buildingAccess.exitDate`.

I have tried a few things but am stuck at:

```
    select 
        BA.building,
        BA.person,
        BA.enteryDate,
        IFNULL(BA.exitDate, NOW()),
        IFNULL(
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                '<p>',
                BN.observationDate, ': ',
                BN.observer, ': ', BN.note,
                '</p>'
                ORDER BY BN.observationDate ASC
                SEPARATOR ''
            ), 
            ''
        )
    from
        buildingAccess BA
        LEFT JOIN buildingNotes BN ON 
            BN.building = BA.building
            AND BN.observationDate BETWEEN BA.enteryDate AND BA.exitDate
    group by BN.building
```

This returns:

```
+----------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| building | person        | enteryDate          | exitDate            | observations                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+----------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Lot B-3  | Charlotte Ahn | 2015-12-01 05:29:14 | 2016-01-23 23:04:04 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| Lot B-3  | Alice Jones   | 2015-11-10 05:29:14 | 2015-11-10 15:18:42 | <p>2015-11-10 05:32:12: Alice Jones: burned out light on pole South-22</p><p>2015-11-10 05:39:12: Alice Jones: burned out light on pole West-7</p><p>2015-11-10 05:42:12: Alice Jones: overfull trash can near pole North-11</p> |
+----------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I expected to see all of the other `buildingAccess` records even if there were no `buildingNotes` records.

I am assuming that I am not "grouping by" the right things but i have not found the right combination yet.

Pointers?

Comment: Can you add whta would be the desired result for your current data set example, please?

Comment: Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html the MySQL so called *extension* to GROUP BY gives you the impression you can use only one column ref in the group by clause but many more non-aggregating columns in the select clause. This is bogus, the results can be bogus, Try your query but this time **GROUP BY BA.building,  BA.person, BA.enteryDate** note the change to BA.building as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is due to use BN.building which is from the outer joined table in the GROUP BY clause. Try the following:

```
SELECT
      BA.building
    , BA.person
    , BA.enteryDate
    , IFNULL(BA.exitDate, NOW())
    , IFNULL (
              GROUP_CONCAT (
                            '<p>',
                            BN.observationDate, ': ',
                            BN.observer, ': ', BN.note,
                            '</p>'
                            ORDER BY BN.observationDate ASC
                            SEPARATOR ''
                            )
                ,''
              )
FROM buildingAccess BA
      LEFT JOIN buildingNotes BN ON BN.building = BA.building
                  AND BN.observationDate BETWEEN BA.enteryDate AND BA.exitDate
GROUP BY
      BA.building
    , BA.person
    , BA.enteryDate
    , IFNULL(BA.exitDate, NOW())
```

It s possible this is too many rows, and perhaps you need some other way to handle (for example) only getting the date rather than full datetime. However you should routinely specify ALL the non-aggregating columns of a query in the group by caluse. See [MySQL GROUP BY Extension](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)